# Can't install following python library and packages on Mac

Tags: macos, python-2.7, python-import

My Python program:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from pylab            import plot,show
from numpy            import vstack,array
from numpy.random     import rand
from scipy.cluster.vq import kmeans, vq, whiten

import csv

if __name__ == "__main__":

    K = 3

    data_arr = []

    clust_name_arr = []

    with open('clustering.csv', 'rb') as f:

        reader = csv.reader(f)

        for row in reader:

            data_arr.append([float(x) for x in row[1:]])

            clust_name_arr.append([row[0]])

    data = vstack( data_arr )

    clust_name = vstack(clust_name_arr)

   data = whiten(data)



    centroids, distortion = kmeans(data,3)

    print "distortion = " + str(distortion)



    idx,_ = vq(data,centroids)



    plot(data[idx==0,0], data[idx==0,1],'ob',

         data[idx==1,0], data[idx==1,1],'or',

         data[idx==2,0], data[idx==2,1],'og')

    print clust_name

    print data

    for i in range(K):

        result_names = clust_name[idx==i, 0]

        print "================================="

        print "Cluster " + str(i+1)

        for name in result_names:

            print name

    plot(centroids[:,0],

         centroids[:,1],

         'sg',markersize=8)

    show()
```

Error Message:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users//Desktop/Assignment4(2).py", line 7, in 
    from pylab            import plot,show
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pylab.py", line 1, in 
    from matplotlib.pylab import *
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pylab.py", line 222, in 
    from matplotlib import mpl  # pulls in most modules
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl.py", line 1, in 
    from matplotlib import artist
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 7, in 
    from transforms import Bbox, IdentityTransform, TransformedBbox, \
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/transforms.py", line 35, in 
    from matplotlib._path import (affine_transform, count_bboxes_overlapping_bbox,
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/_path.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/_path.so: no matching architecture in universal wrapper

Comment: Did you have a question? What did you try? How did you install Python? What are the error messages? Come on - please try harder if you want help.

Comment: I already installed python version 3.7 but I want to know how I  import  python libraries in my  program. pylab, numpy etc.Error message:

Comment: Please click `edit` under your original question and make sure you include answers for *all* the questions in my first comment.

Comment: I include the error message

Comment: And my other 2 questions?